Update vivo V21 to latest Android version
How can I update my old Android version to the latest Android version, in vivo V21, without rooting and any other process, and what is the official process?

vivo V21 was released with Android 11 and got an update to 12. As long as you don't have any special version (e.g. branded by an MNO) Android 12 seems to be the latest official version released for your phone.

The Vivo V21 was released in May 2021, with Android 11. Google stopped supporting Android 11 in February 2024.
You seem to be asking for an all-official process to update to Android 14. The only way for such a process to exist is if Vivo offers it. If they don't, there is no official process.
The reason for this is that Android isn't produced as a generic operating system, as Microsoft Windows is. Instead, Android needs to be customised for each device's hardware. Only the manufacturer has the source code for their customisations.
If Vivo released their customisations as open source, it might be possible for other people and organisation to produce Android for your phone. However, it still wouldn't be "official" and there would be potential difficulties:

If the customisations contained binary "blobs" of code, those may not be compatible with a later Android Framework or Linux kernel.
Even if any blobs were compatible, there would not be a way to fix security vulnerabilities or bugs in them.

The best-known unofficial Android is LineageOS, but that doesn't seem to support any Vivo devices. You appear to be stuck.
One of the advantages of buying Android devices from the biggest brands is that you get longer-term support. I have a Samsung A52 which was released about the same time as your Vivo, also with Android 11. Samsung have provided upgrades as far as Android 14, with no effort on my part, and are still producing security patches for it.

Even if the manufacturer provides the modifications, integrating them into a new Android (and kernel) version can be impossible if the modifications contain "binary blobs" that are only compatible to old kernel or Android version. Also those binary blobs would also stay the same even if they contain known problems or vulnerabilities.

@Robert: Thanks, added.
